# Jquery Ajax Typo3 Problem - loads homepage

Tags: jquery, ajax, typo3

I have the following problem:

I added the following code into a page inside Typo3 (.../index.php?id=18). (The content type of the content element is pure html (special->html).)

```
<select name="testvariable" id="testvariable">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<div id="testformsuccess"></div>
```

When I call the following Javascript, everything works fine:

```
$("#testvariable").change(function(){
if ($('#testvariable').val() == '1') {
    $("#testformsuccess").html('1');
}
if ($('#testvariable').val() == '2') {
    $("#testformsuccess").html('2');
}

return false;
});
```

But as soon, as I try to make an Ajax-call, the hompepage of the typo3-project is beeing loaded instead of the Ajax response inside the destination div "testformsuccess". Here is mey Ajax-code:

```
$("#testvariable").change(function(){
$('#testformsuccess').html('');
$.post("../../php/formtest.php", $("#testvariable").serialize(),  function(response) {   
$('#testformsuccess').html(response);
});
return false;
});
```

My php is:

```
<?php
echo "Hello";
?>
```

I already found out that the reason seems to be something like the page-ID to which the responmse is being sent back. But I do not have a clue how to fix it...

Does anyone know the solution?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery function `$.post()` requires a valid URL as the first parameter (see [API documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)). Try to request the PHP script as follows, assuming the script is located in the root of your web instance:
`$.post("/formtest.php", ...);` or: `$.post("http://example.com/formtest.php", ...);`

Comment: Hello Michael, that exactly solved my issue. Thank you very much!